# Calling Delete rest API by posting some JSON data in protractor tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, protractor, superagent

I have Delete API which will delete already registered email Ids before running my registration script.

Can someone please help me with a way to call it?

I have tried super-agent node module as below. But it didn't work

```
sa.delete('https://***')
    .send({"insured":"abc@gmail.com"})
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .end((err,res)=>{});;
```

Comment: Describe in greater detail what you mean by "didn't work".  Did you get an error?  Did you get an HTTP response?  What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I didn't get any error. But email is not getting deleted. I got response as below when I do console.log()
null: Response {domain: null, _events: Object, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, res: IncomingMessage, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to achieve this using restler node module executing as below:

```
restler.del('<url>';,{data:{"insured":emailId}}).on('complete', function (result) { 
if (result instanceof Error) { 
defered.reject(result.message) 
} 
else { 
defered.fulfill(result); 
} 
});
```

Regards,
Naresh Surya

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once -

```
sa.delete('https://***')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .send({"insured":"abc@gmail.com"})    
    .end((err,res)=>{});
```

Comment: Hi eduPeeth,
no luck. It's not deleting.

-Naresh Surya